# 19.04 on Surface Studio Nvidia drivers not running

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I've installed the recommended driver version 418 `nvidia-driver-418` using the Ubuntu Software & Updates GUI.

My secure boot is disabled.

`$ prime-select query` returns only `nvidia`

```
$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

```
$ sudo prime-select nvidia
Info: the nvidia profile is already set
```

I have rebooted several times, just in-case.

Any help with where to look next would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was remarkably simple.

I downloaded the LATEST drivers from nvidia.com, and installed them.

I was having an installation error with the ones I downloaded previously as they were for an old kernel.